# Restricting specific patch of road using overlays

Tags: here-api

I am trying to implement overlay in HERE map to restrict specific path of a road.
To achieve this i am referring to following guidelines:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/dev_guide/topics/custom-routes.html

The road which i am trying to restrict for routing is around 5km long.

Important thing over here is to get shape points in following format:
An array of shape points where each shape point is an array of two elements, latitude and longitude, in WGS-84 degrees. Currently, the first and last point must each fit within 5 meters tolerance onto existing links. These points must not both end up on the same link.

My basic question is how one can get shape points for desired route in above format.
I tried calculating route between 2 waypoints and added all shape points received by calculateroute response in upload.json request.

Request was successful although route never gets ignored.

Following are my route request parameters:

```
routeRequestParams = {
      mode: 'fastest;car',
      representation: 'display',
      routeattributes : 'waypoints,summary,shape,legs',
      maneuverattributes: 'direction,action',
      waypoint0: '24.799113,46.867249',
            waypoint1: '24.676569,46.641192',
      overlays:'OVERLAYBLOCK11'
    };
```

Kindly let me know what am i missing.

BR,
Harshal

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following format to restrict or add any link in the overlay. Try your use case in our map and also share the entire request "https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/custom_routing_basic"

/2/overlays/upload.json
?map_name=OVERLAYBASICDEMO1&overlay_spec=
[{"op":"override",
"shape":[[50.10765,8.68774],[50.10914,8.68771]],
"layer":"LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FCn",
"data":{"VEHICLE_TYPES":"0"}},
{"op":"create",
"shape":[[50.10937,8.68422],[50.10807,8.68525],[50.10737,8.68387]],
"data":{"NAMES":"ENGBNDemo Road"}}]
&app_id=inCUge3uprAQEtRaruyaZ8&app_code=9Vyk_MElhgPCytA7z3iuPA
&storage=readonly

eg [{"op":"restrict","shape":[[53.54742,9.99704],[53.54746,9.99765]], "type":"preferred", "data":{"VEHICLE_TYPES":"145","PREFERRED_ROUTE_TYPE":"201","ENTRY_PENALTY":-1,"DRIVE_PENALTY":-0.1}}]

Comment: "shape":[[24.695871,46.732799],[24.697474,46.735212],[24.700655,46.73998],[24.706691,46.749368],[24.712005,46.757912],[24.712051,46.757995]],
"layer":"LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FCn",
"data":{"VEHICLE_TYPES":"0","TRAVEL_DIRECTION":"B"}}],
&app_id=<>&app_code=<>
&storage=readonly

This only works with following waypoints. If swapped it wont work.
waypoint0=24.676569,46.641192&waypoint1=24.799113,46.867249

Also if i try to achive this in JS it wont work.
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/2.1.0/heremaps/jsfiddle-github/tree/master/map-with-route-from-a-to-b

Comment: How can one use custom route extension API in Android SDK and in JS ?